# Trouble with Escaping Closing Curly Brace [AHK 1.1.30.03]

Tags: autohotkey

In this AutohotKey script (AHK version 1.1.30.03), I want to save a block of code in the clipboard and paste it by executing Ctrl + V.

The problem I'm having is that, from the last closing curly brace of the last if statement, AHK is interpreting the text as code instead of plain text. (See attached image).

I have tried escaping said brace by prepending a backtick as indicated in the documentation, but it does not work **`}** (https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/EscapeChar.htm). I've also tried putting a double closing brace to escape it, but that didn't work either **}}**

**Syntax error I point out**

[image]

**AHK code script**

```
^*!p::
ClipboardBackup:=ClipboardAll 
Clipboard =
(
    if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
        console.error('some error');
    } else {
        function handleComponentClick(event) {
            if (event.ctrlKey) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                let target = jQuery(event.target);
                if (!target.is('[data-sap-ui]')) {
                    target = target.closest('[data-sap-ui]');
                }
                if (target.length) {
                    console.log("%c ID clicked: %c" + target.attr('id') || 'ID dont found',
                        "background:MediumAquaMarine; color:black; font-size: 0.8rem; padding: 2px 0; border-radius: 2px;font-weight: bold;",
                        "background:white; color:black; font-size: 0.8rem; padding: 2px 5px; border-radius: 2px;"
                    );
                }
            }
        }

    } ;Else close curly brace
)
ClipWait, 2
SendInput, ^v
sleep, 50 
Clipboard:=ClipboardBackup 
return
```

Thanks,
Hotomol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percent signs must be [escaped](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/EscapeChar.htm) and the parenthesis at line 19 as well because the script interprets it as the end of the text that has to be copied:

```
^*!p::
ClipboardBackup:=ClipboardAll 
Clipboard =
(
    if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
        console.error('some error');
    } else {
        function handleComponentClick(event) {
            if (event.ctrlKey) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                let target = jQuery(event.target);
                if (!target.is('[data-sap-ui]')) {
                    target = target.closest('[data-sap-ui]');
                }
                if (target.length) {
                    console.log("`%c ID clicked: `%c" + target.attr('id') || 'ID dont found',
                        "background:MediumAquaMarine; color:black; font-size: 0.8rem; padding: 2px 0; border-radius: 2px;font-weight: bold;",
                        "background:white; color:black; font-size: 0.8rem; padding: 2px 5px; border-radius: 2px;"
                    `) ;
                }
            }
        }

    } ;Else close curly brace
)
ClipWait, 2
SendInput, ^v
sleep, 50 
Clipboard:=ClipboardBackup 
return
```

Comment: It worked...       ...What I can't understand is why that precise parenthesis was being interpreted as code an not the others.